# How to implement distributed task executed on GG Node against segment of the IMDB located on it?

Tags: gridgain

I have partitioned  (IMDB) I would like to start a compute task on each node which do some calculation on each node IMDB against ALL records on THE node it was executed. Thus each task do a part of the job.
it seems that that colocation is not quite possible since I can not restrict access to the data on the node.
Please confirm or suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking how to collocate computations with nodes on where the data is cached. You can take a look at [CacheAffinityExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/CacheAffinityExample.java) shipped with GridGain. Specifically, the following code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < KEY_CNT; i++) {
    final int key = i;

    // This callable will execute on the remote node where
    // data with the given key is located.
    grid.compute().affinityCall(CACHE_NAME, key, new GridCallable() {
        @Override public void call() throws Exception {
            String val = cache.get(key);

            // Work on cached value.
            ...

            return val;
        }
    }).get();
}
```

Comment: Yes I would like to collocate but not by the key but by the node. "go to a node and do calculation agains all data on the node"

Answer (score 0):

This code will send a closure to every node and do calculation against all data on the node:

```
grid.forCache("mycache").compute().broadcast(new GridRunnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        for (GridCacheEntry<K, V> e : cache.entrySet()) {
            // Do something
            ... 
        }
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: I have just tried. it does not work as I expected. cache.entrySet() returns ALL existing keys from all nodes not Just from The node

Comment: private static void hello(final Grid g) throws GridException {
        // Print out hello message on all nodes.
        g.forCache(CACHE_NAME).compute().broadcast(
                new GridRunnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Hi from LA! :)");
                        int i = 1;
                        for (GridCacheEntry<?,?> e : g.cache(CACHE_NAME).entrySet()) {
                            System.out.println(i++);
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).get();
  }

Comment: The code from above was implanted to Your example  ComputeBroadcastExample.java

Comment: cache.entrySet() includes elements only from local node. The reason you got confused is most likely because local node also may be storing backups for keys cached on other nodes. If you need only primary entry set (excluding backups), then you should use GridCacheProjection.primaryEntrySet() method.